# Error thrown when building a required result object with Postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I have a similar table as below:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|       id     |        name         |       channel_name        |
|____________________________________|_________________________ _|
|       1      |       my name 1     |         channel_1         |
|       2      |       my name 2     |         channel_2         |
|       3      |       my name 3     |         channel_3         |
|       4      |       my name 4     |         channel_4         |
```

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT
    mt.id as id,
    (
        SELECT
            mt2.name as event,
            mt2.channel_name as channel
        FROM my_table
        INNER JOIN my_table mt2 on (mt2.id = mt.id)
    ) as data
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.name ILIKE '%name 2%';
```

The response should be,

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "data": {
        "event": "my name 2",
        "channel": "channel_2",
    }
}
```

This is throwing an error,

```
subquery must return only one column
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a subquery (to select something from a different table or so), you just want [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
SELECT
    mt.id as id,
    json_build_object(
        'event', mt.name,
        'channel', mt.channel_name
    ) as data
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.name ILIKE '%name 2%';
```

Alternatively you *could* use `to_json` on a subquery (to make it return a JSON object instead of a tuple), but still you'd want to select from the same row of the same table `mt`:

```
SELECT
    mt.id as id,
    to_json(
        SELECT
            mt.name as event,
            mt.channel_name as channel
    ) as data
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.name ILIKE '%name 2%';
```

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I need. Is it possible to stringify the `data` key afterwards? Something like a `to_string` method, like `to_string(json_build_object('event', mt.name, 'channel', mt.channel_name )) as data`. I'd need this, because my GraphQL server returns `data` as a string type (`GraphQLString`)

Comment: Yes, but `json` basically is a string representation already. If you want the JSON string instead, instruct node-postgres not to parse it into an object.

Comment: "*my GraphQL server returns `data` as a string type*" - you really need to fix that. Do not transport structured data as strings.